# How to avoid creating foreign key in Doctrine migration (bidirectional, with Single-table inheritance)?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

got one issue with Doctrine.
Here is bidirectional ManyToOne-OneToMany association

```
class InternetPlan extends BaseProduct
...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\PricingType", inversedBy="internetPlans")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pricing_type_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * @JMS\Exclude()
     */
    private $pricingType;
```

The parent class is

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductsRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType(value="SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap(
 *     {
 *     InternetPlan::type = "InternetPlan",
 *     TVPlan::type = "TVPlan",
 *     AdditionalServicePlan::type = "AdditionalServicePlan",
 *     Device::type = "Device"
 *     }
 *    )
 */
abstract class BaseProduct
```

And inversed side is

```
class PricingType
...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\InternetPlan", mappedBy="pricingType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     * @JMS\Type("object_ids")
     */
    private $internetPlans;
```

**PROBLEM**: when i execute *doctrine:migrations:diff*, it wants to create foreign key constraint in the parent table base product, ignoring my JoinColumn(nullable=true) annotation.

```
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE base_product ADD CONSTRAINT FK_E74CBDC94B70279 FOREIGN KEY (pricing_type_id) REFERENCES pricing_type (id)');
```

But of course, when i'm executing migration then get the following error

```
 An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE base_product ADD CONSTRAINT FK_E74CBDC94B70279 FOREIGN KEY (pricing_type_id) REFERENCES pricing_type (id)':                                                                                      

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`taskman42`.`#sql-1_20`, CONSTRAINT `FK_E74CBDC94B70279` FOREIGN KEY (`pricing_type_id`) REFERENCES `pricing_type` (`id`))
```

So i need to remove this line by-hand from every newer migration.

**The main question is**: How can i avoid this line in every new migration?

Comment: Just before the `FOREIGN KEY` line, you should have something like `ALTER TABLE base_product ADD pricing_type_id INT DEFAULT NULL` in your migration, right ?

Comment: nullable=true does NOT mean, that the collumn shouldn't exist nor that it's not a foreign key. nullable true only means, that it may be allowed to not have the relation set for entities in general, which still makes it necessary to have the column and very very very advisable to have a foreign key constraint. You probably can avoid this line when you properly set up that relation... which is a question of how that column is defined in the database, and it should be as Lucas Delobelle describes.

Comment: since your foreign key didn't exist before, it's quite likely, that there are records/rows in your database that violate the constraint, possibly by having a pricing_type_id that doesn't exist as pricing_type.id

Answer (score 0):

Jakumi was right, the main reason that i've forget to put JoinColumn(nullable=true) initially... And after this, i've created an object, that was subclass of BaseProduct, so that object has pricing_type_id=0 - that's why foreign key constraint was so ugly.

```
UPDATE base_product SET pricing_type_id=NULL WHERE pricing_type_id=0
```

This SQL was helpful